# Вылазит или вылезает?

Tags: этимология, грамотная-речь

Интересно, что разговорное "вылазит" гораздо чаще употребляется в нашей речи, чем литературное "вылезает". И желающих его вернуть в нормы русского языка предостаточно. Например: "Он не вылазит с европейских выставок!" - не знаю как вам, но мне слух режет очень сильно.

Comment: «Не знаю как вам». Но, что «желающих его вернуть в нормы русского языка предостаточно», знаете.

Answer (score 2):

Мне тоже "не вылазит" изрядно режет слух. Но "затолкнуть обратно" вряд ли получится. Слишком уж обнаглела эта форма, вон её даже до нормативной поднимают некоторые граждане на том основании, что она якобы не просторечная.

Но тут вот какая штука. Есть строго нормативный глагол "лазить", глагол движения (соотнесенный с "лезть"). Глагол "лазать" фиксируется как парный к нему, тоже строго нормативный, но менее употребительный. Нормативное образование "вылезать" соотносится и с "лазать" и с "лазить", но порождено скорее формой "лазать". И другие производные обычно происходят от "лазать", но соотнесены с обеими формами. Это не всегда ощущается даже носителями языка, возникает какая-то потребность в форме, образованной напрямую от "лазить", таковыми порождениями от "лазить"и является личные формы типа "вылазит", вылажу (и даже "вылазию"), "вылазите".

Вот таким образом, образуя производные по общему правилу от "лазить",  носители как бы восстанавливают в правах эту форму "лазить".

Но на настоящий момент "вылазить" - **форма просторечная**. Смотрите, например, у Зарвы. К тому же она не ко всем значениям применима.

UPD

Забыл еще один момент упомянуть. Тут еще путаются формы от парного (по принципу глагола-движения) "лезть". Они тоже частично совпадают с формами от "лазить"/"лазать", и это тоже приводит к потребности использовать неомонимичные к ним формы.